# Write multiple rows from dict using csv

Tags: python, csv

**Update**: I do not want to use `pandas` because I have a list of dict's and want to write each one to disk as they come in (part of webscraping workflow).

I have a dict that I'd like to write to a csv file. I've come up with a solution, but I'd like to know if there's a more `pythonic` solution available. Here's what I envisioned (but doesn't work):

```
import csv
test_dict = {"review_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
             "text": [5, 6, 7, 8]}

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["review_id", "text"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(test_dict)
```

Which would ideally result in:

```
review_id text
        1    5
        2    6
        3    7
        4    8
```

The code above doesn't seem to work that way I'd expect it to and throws a value error. So, I've  turned to following solution (which does work, but seems verbose).

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["review_id", "text"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    response = test_dict
    cells = [{x: {key: val}} for key, vals in response.items()
             for x, val in enumerate(vals)]
    rows = {}
    for d in cells:
        for key, val in d.items():
          if key in rows:
            rows[key].update(d.get(key, None))
          else:
            rows[key] = d.get(key, None)     
    for row in [val for _, val in rows.items()]:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Again, to reiterate what I'm looking for: the block of code directly above works (i.e., produces the desired result mentioned early in the post), but seems verbose. So, is there a more `pythonic` solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe `DictWriter` expects a `list` of `dict`s rather than a `dict` of `list`s. See the example here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Answer (score 1):

Your first example will work with minor edits. `DictWriter` expects a `list` of `dict`s rather than a `dict` of `list`s. Assuming you can't change the format of the `test_dict`:

```
import csv
test_dict = {"review_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
             "text": [5, 6, 7, 8]}

def convert_dict(mydict, numentries):
    data = []
    for i in range(numentries):
        row = {}
        for k, l in mydict.iteritems():
            row[k] = l[i]
        data.append(row)
    return data

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["review_id", "text"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(convert_dict(test_dict, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a 3rd-party package, you could do it with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(test_dict).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

**update**

So, you have several dictionaries and all of them seems to come from a scraping routine.

```
import pandas as pd

test_dict = {"review_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
             "text": [5, 6, 7, 8]}
pd.DataFrame(test_dict).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

list_of_dicts = [test_dict, test_dict]
for d in list_of_dicts:
    pd.DataFrame(d).to_csv('test.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

This time, you would be appending to the file and without the header.

The output is:

```
review_id,text
1,5
2,6
3,7
4,8
1,5
2,6
3,7
4,8
1,5
2,6
3,7
4,8
```

Comment: The reason I'm not using `pandas` is because looping over multiple dictionaries (a list of test_dict's) and I want to write each to a row to disk.

Comment: @RyanErwin But all in the same 'test.csv'  file?

Comment: yes, so assuming they're all the same size as test_dict, same keys, with different values, then each would add four new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas of python..

Here is a simple example

```
import pandas as pd
test_dict = {"review_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
         "text": [5, 6, 7, 8]}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(test_dict)
d1.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Cheers

Comment: The reason I'm not using `pandas` is because looping over multiple dictionaries (a list of test_dict's) and I want to write each to a row to disk.

Comment: Do u have a list of dict something like that:
 [{'review_id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'text': [5, 6, 7, 8]},{'review_id2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'text2': [5, 6, 7, 8]}]
and you want to create a csv out of it with review_id as column 1, text as col2, and so on.. ?? Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) can join together different iterables into tuples which can be passed to `writerows`. Try this as the last line:

```
writer.writerows(zip(test_dict["review_id"], test_dict["text"]))
```

You can see what it's doing by making a list:

```
>>> list(zip(test_dict["review_id"], test_dict["text"]))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

**Edit**: In this particular case, you probably want a regular [csv.Writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects), since what you effectively have is now a list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `DictWriter.writerows()` you are forced to have a dict for each row. Instead you can simply add the values changing your csv creation:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
     fieldnames = test_dict.keys()
     fieldvalues = zip(*test_dict.values())

     writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
     writer.writerow(fieldnames)
     writer.writerows(fieldvalues)
```

Comment: This example relies on dictionary iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different problems in your question:

1. Create a csv file from a dictionary where the values are containers and not primitives.

For the first problem, the solution is generally to transform the container type into a primitive type.  The most common method is creating a json-string.  So for example:

```
>>> import json
>>> x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> json_string = json.dumps(x)
>>> json_string
'[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]'
```

So your data conversion might look like:

```
import json


def convert(datadict):
    '''Generator which converts a dictionary of containers into a dictionary of json-strings.

    args:
        datadict(dict): dictionary which needs conversion

    yield:
        tuple: key and string
    '''
    for key, value in datadict.items():
        yield key, json.dumps(value)


def dump_to_csv_using_dict(datadict, fields=None, filepath=None, delimiter=None):
    '''Dumps a datadict value into csv

    args:
        datadict(list): list of dictionaries to dump
        fieldnames(list): field sequence to use from the dictionary [default: sorted(datadict.keys())]
        filepath(str): filepath to save to  [default: 'tmp.csv']
        delimiter(str): delimiter to use in csv [default: '|']
    '''
    fieldnames = sorted(datadict.keys()) if fields is None else fields
    filepath = 'tmp.csv' if filepath is None else filepath
    delimiter = '|' if not delimiter else delimiter
    with open(filepath, 'w') as csvfile:
       writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='ignore', delimiter=delimiter)
       writer.writeheader()
       for each_dict in datadict:
           writer.writerow(each_dict)
```

So the naive conversion looks like this:

```
# Conversion code
test_data = {
    "review_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
         "text": [5, 6, 7, 8]}
}

converted_data = dict(convert(test_data))
data_list = [converted_data]
dump_to_csv(data_list)
```

2. Create a final value that is actually some sort of a merging of two disparate data sets.

To do this, you need to find a way to combine data from different keys.  This is not an easy problem to generically solve.

That said, it's easy to combine two lists with zip.

```
>>> x = [2, 4, 6]
>>> y = [1, 3, 5]
>>> zip(y, x)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

In addition, in the event that your lists are not the same size, python's itertools package provides a method, izip_longest, which will yield back the full zip even if one list is shorter than another.  Note izip_longest returns a generator.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
>>> x = [2, 4]
>>> y = [1, 3, 5]
>>> z = izip_longest(y, x, fillvalue=None)  # default fillvalue is None
>>> list(z)  # z is a generator
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, None)]
```

So we could add another function here:

```
from itertoops import izip_longest

def combine(data, fields=None, default=None):
    '''Combines fields within data

    args:
        data(dict): a dictionary with lists as values
        fields(list): a list of keys to combine [default: all fields in random order]
        default: default fill value [default: None]
    yields:
        tuple: columns combined into rows
    '''
    fields = data.keys() if field is None else field
    columns = [data.get(field) for field in fields]
    for values in izip_longest(*columns, fillvalue=default):
        yield values
```

And now we can use this to update our original conversion.

```
def dump_to_csv(data, filepath=None, delimiter=None):
    '''Dumps list into csv

    args:
        data(list): list of values to dump
        filepath(str): filepath to save to  [default: 'tmp.csv']
        delimiter(str): delimiter to use in csv [default: '|']
    '''
    fieldnames = sorted(datadict.keys()) if fields is None else fields
    filepath = 'tmp.csv' if filepath is None else filepath
    delimiter = '|' if not delimiter else delimiter
    with open(filepath, 'w') as csvfile:
       writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter)
       for each_row in data:
           writer.writerow(each_dict)

# Conversion code
test_data = {
    "review_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
         "text": [5, 6, 7, 8]}
}

combined_data = combine(test_data)
data_list = [combined_data]
dump_to_csv(data_list)
```